# How to embed a filled Region in a Graphics?

Tags: graphics, regions, plotting

Let for example:

```
regn = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
```

The only documented way I found to draw a gereric region `regn` filled is a bit "complex":

```
RegionPlot[RegionMember[regn, {x, y}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a direct way to make a `Graphics` object with some filled generic region `regn` and other graphics primitives like `Line`, `Disk`, `Rectangle` without resorting to use `RegionPlot` and then `Show` to combine different `Graphic`-s?

I'm interested to a generic way for a generic region, not only for the region in the example.

Comment: What do you mean with "*not exactly readable*"?

Comment: Graphics[{Lighter[Blue], Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appear that plotting a `Region` can be simply done by passing the region to `RegionPlot` without any range specification. At the time the question was asked this use of `RegionPlot` wasn't documented.

```
regn = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
RegionPlot[regn]
```

My question was originally also about a way to combine a filled region with Others graphics primitives without using `Show`. I think `Show` it's an effective way to do this, if we want to keep the region's generality, but have a look at the Mr.Wizard answer.

Comment: Thanks for the self-answer; I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 6):

Building on your self-answer here is an example of using the primitives generated by `RegionPlot` inside another `Graphics` expression:

```
regn = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];

elem = RegionPlot[regn][[1]];

Graphics[{Polygon[{{-2, -2}, {3, 3}, {-2, 3}, {3, -2}}], 
  elem, {Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, 1.5, {Pi/4, 3 Pi/4}]}}]
```

[image]

If a different style is needed for the region its hard-coded `Directive`s can be stripped:

```
elem2 = DeleteCases[elem, _Directive, -1];

Graphics[{Polygon[{{-2, -2}, {3, 3}, {-2, 3}, {3, -2}}],
  {Brown, elem2}, {Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, 1.5, {Pi/4, 3 Pi/4}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and effective, as you are used to be, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of achieve it with `DiscretizeRegion` and `BoundaryMesh`

```
regn = BoundaryMesh@DiscretizeRegion@
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]

Show[regn, Graphics@Line[{{0, 0}, {3, 1}}]]
```

> [image: Region with line]

`MeshRegion`s (what `DiscretizeRegion` generates) have many styling options.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `MeshPrimitives` function allows us to move toward a more canonical way of adding regions to `Graphics(3D)` without resorting to `RegionPlot` + extraction + style deletion. Here is Mr. Wizard's second example converted to this form and another example in 3D, which is what I was tinkering with that led me to this question.

```
Graphics[{Polygon[{{-2, -2}, {3, 3}, {-2, 3}, {3, -2}}], {Brown, 
   EdgeForm@Brown, 
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion@regn, 1 | 2]}, {Orange, 
   Disk[{0, 0}, 1.5, {Pi/4, 3 Pi/4}]}}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Gray, Opacity@.2, Sphere[], Brown, Opacity@1, 
  Cuboid[{-1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, -1}], Blue, 
  MeshPrimitives[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
    RegionDifference[Ball[], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1/3}, {1, 1, 1}]], 2]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]