# HIghlight intersection of two disks

Tags: geometry

I tried this:

```
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];
reg2 = Disk[{1, 0}, 1];
reg3 = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
```

Then this:

```
Graphics[{
  Opacity[0.5],
  {Red, reg1},
  {Green, reg2},
  {Blue, reg3}
  }]
```

But it doesn't work because (I think) the RegionIntersection did not send back a Graphics Primitive.

What's the best way to show the intersection of these two disks, including the two disks?

Comment: If you just want to show the three regions, then why not remove reg3 from your Graphics command?  You then have a red circle, a green circle, and some other color showing the intersection.

Comment: It looks to me like the main issue you're after is the same as discussed in the following link:  [How to embed a filled Region in a Graphics?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66234/how-to-embed-a-filled-region-in-a-graphics)

Answer (score 10):

Use `RegionPlot` for regions:

```
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];
reg2 = Disk[{1, 0}, 1];
reg3 = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
RegionPlot[{reg1, reg2, reg3},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[Opacity[.5], {Red, Blue, Green}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];

reg2 = Disk[{1, 0}, 1];

Show[Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], {Red, reg1}, {Green, reg2}}],DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2]]]
```

[image]